# Datastore aggregate function with where clause

Tags: google-app-engine, aggregate-functions, google-cloud-datastore

I'm currently building an mobile app with a GAE backend. I'm tossing up between CloudSQL & the Datastore  for persistence. I would prefer to use the data store as I will be storing a lot of data (and it's cheaper). One of the requirements of my app will be to report on the sum of hours a user devoted to an activity for a given date range. I understand that Sum() functions on the Datastore aren't really possible because of it's distributed nature and that a counter should be used and updated on each insert/delete. However I'm not quite sure how this would work if I have to report the sum for a given date range. I could possibly keep counters for Total hours ever, Year to date, month & week. But this is still fairly limiting as I wouldn't be able to get the hours devoted from say 23rd Jan - 15 Aug. Plus it seems like a lot redundant data...

Is there any way to implement this type of aggregation in the datastore? Or is CloudSQL my only option.

I understand that Sum() isn't a thing on the datastore but I guess I'm trying to find some way to implement the datastore equivalent of the following (simplified) SQL:

```
SELECT sum(hours) 
FROM {activity table} 
WHERE {activity_date} between {min_date} and {max_date}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, SQL accumulators are more efficient, but the app engine datastore will scale more efficiently for very large datasets.  To answer your specific question: If each entity has a [Date](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#Date_and_Time) property activity_date and int prop hours, create a [search index](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes) for (activity_date, hours), then use an ancestor projection query:

```
SELECT entity.date, entity.hours where entity.date > {min_date} sort by entity.date ascending and __key__ starts_with (Activity, 'Foosball')
```

Then you can add up the hours as long as the entities you receive have a date below your max_date.